# Angular 5 [object Object] error with json

Tags: json, angular, httpclient

I'm trying to load json data via httpclient using get in Angular 5. I'm using a service, interface, component and json file; I've followed a few tutorials already to try and get this to work as well as verified my json with [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/). From what I can see, everything should function, the json should be parsed and everything should be fine except I get ***'error: [object Object]'*** in the console every time. I've tried various things to fix it, such as

```
data => this.jsonArticles = Object.values(data);
this.articles = data[0];
```

but I can't get my data into any other form.

**article.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Article } from './article';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ArticleService {

  // Variables
  private _jsonUrl: string = './assets/data.json';

  // Constructors
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Methods
  getArticles(): Observable<Article[]> {
    return this.http.get<Article[]>(this._jsonUrl);      
  }

}
```

**article.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticleService } from '../article.service';
import { Article } from '../article';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article',
  templateUrl: './article.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article.component.scss']
})
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {

  // Variables
  public jsonArticles = [];
  public errorMsg;
  // Consturctors
  constructor(private _articleService: ArticleService) { }

  // Methods
  ngOnInit(){
    this._articleService.getArticles()
      .subscribe( 
        data => this.jsonArticles = data,
        error => this.errorMsg = error);
  }
}
```

**article.ts**

```
export interface Article {
    id: number;
    author: string;
    title: string;
    content: string;
    tags: string[];
    categories: string[];
    publishDate: string;
    published: boolean;
}
```

**data.json**

```
 [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "author": "",
        "title": "Fancy Meat",
        "content": "Strip steak bresaola capicola tail cow chicken corned beef turkey.",
        "tags": ["test", "lorum"],
        "categories": ["blah"],
        "publishDate": "2018-02-12T08:15:00.000-05:00",
        "published": true
    },
]
```

I truncated the json file for brevity, there are more entries in the file making my json object an array and there is no comma after the last entry in the json array.

Comment: post your HTML template code

Comment: what do u get when you print data in subscribe method on console?

Comment: What if you try `/assets/data.json` (without the dot at the beginning)

Comment: @David removing the period did nothing.
@Akanksha When I printed to the console it showed 'status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"'
my folder structure is 

`.article.ts<br>
.article.service.ts
./article/article.component.ts
./assets/data.json'`

somehow my relative path is not accurate....

Comment: @Akanksha, your suggestion got me to the answer, which was that I still had **in-momory-data-service** in my app.module.ts file 
Thanks!

Comment: Glad you have found your answer, but thats not valid json. (Is this a typo or thats actually what you are hoping to receive?)

Comment: If you found the answer of your own answer, please post it, its useful for others!!

Answer (score 5):

I got this error because I forgot to import `HttpClientModule` into `app.module.ts` and declare it into `imports`

```
...
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRouteModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```