# Using HttpClient in Angular Causes Error: "[object Object]"

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple webpage built using Angular that works using a test data 
but I am now integrating it with an API so have imported HTTPClient into one of the services.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Using HttpClient appears to trigger an error shown below.  I have narrowed the problem down to occur as soon as I create an instance of the HttpClient in the constructor "`constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}`" and even without calling it, the webpage does not load and returns this error:

```
ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
resolvePromisehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3136:31resolvePromisehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3093:17scheduleResolveOrRejecthttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3195:17invokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:17onInvokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36912:24invokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:17runTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:28drainMicroTaskQueuehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2917:25 core.js:1673
    defaultErrorLogger core.js:1673
    ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ErrorHandler.prototype.handleError core.js:1719
    next core.js:4311:109
    ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn< core.js:3551:34
    ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub Subscriber.js:196
    ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.next Subscriber.js:134
    ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype._next Subscriber.js:77
    ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype.next Subscriber.js:54
    ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js/Subject.prototype.next Subject.js:47
    ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/EventEmitter.prototype.emit core.js:3535:52
    onHandleError/< core.js:3842:48
    ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke zone.js:388
    ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.run zone.js:138
    ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/NgZone.prototype.runOutsideAngular core.js:3779
    onHandleError core.js:3842
    ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.handleError zone.js:392
    ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.runGuarded zone.js:154
    _loop_1 zone.js:677
    ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</api.microtaskDrainDone zone.js:686
    drainMicroTaskQueue zone.js:602
```

Code Snippet:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

    interface UsefulVariable{
      name: string;
    }

    @Injectable()
    export class SomeClass{

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ....
```

Comment: `as soon as I create an instance of the HttpClient in the constructor` --> are you not using Dependency Injection? Please paste the related code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51369799/4944869 take look might solve your peoblem

Comment: @codeepic, I have updated the question, thanks.

Comment: Check @NimaHakimi link - have you provided `HttpClientModule` in your app module imports?